# How do I get my iPhone browser to honor height: 100%?

Tags: css

I have a web site where the min-width is set to 767px until I can get around to making a purely mobile version.

However, when this is pinched in to view the entire 767 width, the height does not honor the 100%.  It appears to stay at whatever height was set when zoomed out to 1.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

It works fine on landscape, but not on portrait.

How do I fix this?

Edit: Here's a full html that shows the problem...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            min-height: 100vh;
            background: red;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #navbar {
            background: blue;
            min-width: 767px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navbar">Test</div>
    <div ng-view id="mainBody">Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a meta tag for viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

you can use vh unit for full height:

```
#mydiv {
   display:block;
   height:100vh;
}
```

see units from css3 on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: Tried this.  Didn't seem to help.

Comment: Don't forget to set full height to body and html. Found jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/hr8sL/